# pulling data from max field

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table structure with columns similar to the following:

```
ID | line | value
1  |  1   | 10
1  |  2   | 5
2  |  1   | 6
3  |  1   | 7
3  |  2   | 4
```

ideally, i'd like to pull the following:

```
ID | value
1 | 5
2 | 6
3 | 4
```

one solution would be to do something like the following:

```
select a.ID, a.value
from
myTable a
inner join (select id, max(line) as line from myTable group by id) b
    on a.id = b.id and a.line = b.line
```

Given the size of the table and that this is just a part of a larger pull, I'd like to see if there's a more elegant / simpler way of pulling this directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a task for OLAP-functions:

```
select *
from myTable a
qualify
   rank()  -- assign a rank for each id
   over (partition by id
         order by line desc) = 1
```

Might return multiple rows per id if they share the same max line. If you want to return only one of them, add another column to the `order by` to make it unique or switch to `row_number` to get an indeterminate row.

Comment: Thanks, as soon as I have a chance, I'll dive in. The good news is, the ID/Line combination is a unique identifier.